# Ubuntu Bridge Mode from wwan0 to eth0 interfaces

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Hi I have a ATT 4G USB Card and I would like to setup a Bridge Mode for the interface wwan0 to eth0. currently the setup is the following but is not working:

in the /etc/network/interfaces :

iface eth0 inet manual iface wwan0 intet dhcp

auto br0 iface br0 inet dhcp bridge_ports wwan0 eth0

The wwan0 is getting a Public ip with DHCP from ATT for ie. 167.17.25.12 want to accomplish the following : bridge this IP from wwan0 to the interface eth0 .

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ubuntu-desktop ? In this case, I would recommend to use the graphical user interface `network-manager` to add a bridge and therefore, avoid conflicts between configurations...

If you want to create a bridge the hard way, manually, you should set the IP of your bridge globally, and not for each interfaces, as seen on https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#Configuring_bridging_in_.2Fetc.2Fnetwork.2Finterfaces .

Finally, if you just want to re-route traffic from your wwan0 to eth0 interface, you can see this thread : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126595/iptables-forward-all-traffic-to-interface